Looking for the book having a section entitled "The Constant-Delay Network Functions"
Years ago, I have copied few pages from a book. This copy from the chapter "The Constant-Delay Network Functions" is still here but the notes about the authors and title of the book are missing. I remember that this section was very large. I was nearly sure that one of the authors was Ernest Kuh, but searching on the WWW gives me no valuable result. The entire book is related to the time domain behavior of filters.
Please help me to find the full information.

Dunno the book nor the author, but there appears to be a pretty good wikipedia article on this.

The book is called Time-domain Synthesis of Linear Networks by Kendall L. Sue.
